# expire headers and cache control with mod header

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have added expire header in my htaccess file so is there still need to add mod_header for cache-control?
**My expire header is :**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive On 

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

**And My mod_header for cache-control is :**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>


<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What problem you're really facing with above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's read [the documentation for mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) :

> This module controls the setting of the **Expires HTTP header** and the
>   **max-age directive of the Cache-Control HTTP header** in server
>   responses. The expiration date can set to be relative to either the
>   time the source file was last modified, or to the time of the client
>   access.

The answer is therefore: It depends.

mod_expires sets the max-age directive, but does not set the directive that tells the client if the cache is public or private. When nothing is defined, I believe the cache will do a best-effort in determining if it wants to cache this particular response. On the other hand, it isn't possible to set the Expires-header with mod_header.

I think in your case the mod_header rules are obsolete, but you might want to inspect requests in your browser to see if caching happens as you expect.